# WPF TreeView Group By

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have class "Person" that look like this:

```
public class Person
{
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
        public string Country{ get; set; }
        public List<Person> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I want to create a TreeView in WPF that will present the Persons by Country.

For example:

- New york

  - Bob

    - New York

      - Ethan
      - Owen
    - Canada

      - Benjamin
      - James
  - Kevin

    - Paris

      - Louis
  - William
- Finland

  - Oliver

    - Hungary

      - Ben
      - Paul
    - Iceland

      - Arthur

        - Benjamin
    - England

      - Gabriel
      - Victor
  - Eino

    - Paris

      - Gabriel
      - Adam
  - Emma

My TreeView :

```
 <TreeView.Resources>
  <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding People}" DataType="{x:Type Person}">
       <Label Content="{Binding Name}"></Label>
   </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

Is there someway to use "Group by" in tree view?

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, WPF TreeView doesnt support 'Sorting'.
What you could do is use Linq to sort your ItemsCollection. 
That will do the same thing, but your collection will be modified.

Try playing around with linq.. :) you will find it definitely :)